# locationManager:didExitRegion: not called when app is running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location, region

I have an app with a location manager that runs with startUpdatingLocation.  However, if it hasn't moved then i stopUpdatingLocation, mark the current location as a region and startMonitoringForRegion like so:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

CLRegion* region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:self.currentLocation.coordinate radius:25 identifier:@"last_loc"];

[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];

[region release];
```

When the app is completely shut down and I exit the region, locationManager:didExitRegion is called and I continue on my merry way like so:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{       
    [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

However, if the app is running, either in the background or foreground, the app won't respond to locationManager:didExitRegion. What am I missing?

Comment: are you testing on iPhone 4 HW?  Only iPhone 4 HW supports region tracking.

Comment: @timthetoolman, yes, iphone 4.

Comment: did you set the delegate for the location manager?

Comment: @timthetoolman, yup. going to have to revisit this when i get more time i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to initialize the coordinate property. If you want the coordinate to be the user's current location, use `[your location manager].location.coordinate.latitude` and `[your location manager].location.coordinate.longitude` as the initialization properties.  If you require altitude, include `[your location manager].location.altitude`, `[your location manager].location.horizontalAccuracy`, `[your location manager].location.verticalAccuracy`, and `[your location manager].location.timeStamp`.  Without this information, you create a region that has no coordinate, but still exists. Essentially, it has a name, but no real information.